# JQuery table sorter pager with AJAX - sorting not working ok

Tags: tablesorter

I have a problem with JQuery table sorter pager plugin.
I am trying to use paging with AJAX call. It seems to work OK for most cases, but I am unable to get the sorting working.

The problem is that when the request is made it always looks like (assuming the code from example [here](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html)):

```
http:/mydatabase.com?page=0&size=100&{sortList:col}
```

just like the last parameter `{sortList:col}` is never actually replaced with proper sorting column.

If I'm reading the example correctly the request for `sortList = [[2,0],[3,0]]` should actually look like:

```
http:/mydatabase.com?page=0&size=100&col[2]=0&col[3]=0
```

But in my case it never is. Also when I click on the header the sorting is performed, but no request is made.

Is there anything I am missing in the linked example?

**EDIT**

The first part of my problem has been solved by replacing the plugin with the newest version.

For the second part, I still cannot get a request when clicking (sorting) columns. The ajaxProcessing function is almost exactly the same as in the example [here](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html), only headers variable is renamed.

As Mottie sugested I am posting an example result from AJAX call (MS MVC JsonResult):

```
{
"total_rows":1,
"headers":["Id.","Date","User name","File name","status","Hash","Link"],
"rows":[
    {
        "Id":"21",
        "ReceiveDate":"02.12.2012",
        "UserName":"John Doe",
        "FileName":"test.txt",
        "Status":"",
        "Hash":"4A71FD2E12F7E04ED0C04E17476BD1BC5F823C8F",
        "FileNameLink":"\u003ca style=\"padding-left:10px\" href=\"GetFile?Id=21&fileName=test.txt\"\u003eSave\u003c/a\u003e"
    }]
}
```

Regards

Comment: Are you sure you're using the most up-to-date version of tablesorter? It is currently v2.5.2.

Comment: Right, we had version 2.1.7...never thought that version could be a problem because in the docs says 2.0.32. Silly me :) Anyway, now I get the col property set up OK, but is there a way to trigger an AJAX request when a click on header is performed? For example when I click on header "District" on above example I would like a request `http:/mydatabase.com?page=0&size=100&col[3]=0`, and when a click it again `http:/mydatabase.com?page=0&size=100&col[3]=1`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, the `{sortList:col}` was added in v2.4.5, I just forgot to add a note. Can you share your `ajaxProcessing` function and a basic ajax result?

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner... I didn't realize you updated the question above.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize, but I didn't get a chance to thoroughly test the latest changes to the pager. Some of the code was written by someone else, so I might have missed something obvious.

Anyway, this might be the bug that is causing you problems. It resets the table to the first page after each sort... I'll have fixed in the next update.

In the pager plugin, lines 460-470 is this code:

```
.bind('filterEnd.pager sortEnd.pager', function() {
    //Prevent infinite event loops from occuring by setting this in all moveToPage calls and catching it here.
    if ($.data(table, 'pagerUpdateTriggered')) {
        $.data(table, 'pagerUpdateTriggered', false);
        return;
    }
    c.page = 0;
    updatePageDisplay(table, c);
    moveToPage(table, c);
    changeHeight(table, c);
})
```

Just change the `c.page = 0` to this:

```
if (e.type === 'filterEnd') { c.page = 0; }
```

and add an `e` to the `function(e)`.

Comment: Sorry, I've been away a while, so I had no time to test your changes to the pager plugin until now. But even with this changes the behavior is still the same. Please let me know if you need any more information for troubleshooting. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @pierch Did you try the latest version?